# Modify multiple files with same folder name

Tags: bash

Need help in mass renaming files same as folder name without using 'rename' cmd

e.g.

```
/tmp/2017-09-22/cyber.gz
/tmp/2017-09-23/cyber.gz
/tmp/2017-09-24/cyber.tar
```

...........

Above files has to be copy and rename same as folder name and keep in /tmp/archive . Renaming should be done after copying, without impacting above original file

Looks like below

```
/archive/2017-09-22_cyber.gz
/archive/2017-09-23_cyber.gz
/archive/2017-09-24_cyber.tar
```

Comment: Please use code tags for your samples, also do you have list of files which you want to copy or you want to use find command to find all of them? IN case of find command use what should be the criteria to search files inside /tmp? Kindly update your post with same.

Comment: Files are present in /tmp/ as mentioned in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash itself can do exactly what you are attempting to do using builtin *parameter expansion with substring removal*, without having to invoke additional subshells calling external utilities.

Bash provides two basic forms of *parameter expansion with substring removal* (actually four, if you count doing the same thing for shortest and longest independently)

```
${string#substring}     Strip shortest match of $substring from front of $string
${string##substring}    Strip longest match of $substring from front of $string

${string%substring}     Strip shortest match of $substring from back of $string
${string%%substring}    Strip longest match of $substring from back of $string
```

For example if I have `fullfilename=/path/to/my/file.txt` and I want `file.txt` alone, I can use `filename="${fullfilename##*/}"` to "strip the longest match of `"*/"` from the front of `$fullfilename`. (e.g. everything up to, and including, the last `'/'`, leaving `file.txt` in the variable `filename`)

You can solve your problem using `find` to gather all files below `tmp` and then rework the filenames to put them in `/archive` under the correct name with 3 successive applications, e.g.

(I use `ffn` for `fullfilename`, `f` for `filename`, `d` for the full directory path, `last` for the last directory component):

```
while read -r ffn; do 
    f="${ffn##*/}"
    d="${ffn%/"$f"}"
    last="${d##*/}"
    echo "cp -a $ffn /archive/${last}_$f"  ## just showing what would be done
    ## cp -a "$ffn" /archive/"${last}_$f"  ## uncomment to actually copy
done < <(find tmp/ -type f)
```

(add `-ua` to the `cp` options to only copy new or changed files in `tmp`)

**Example Directory Contents**

```
$ tree tmp
tmp
├── 2017-09-22
│   └── cyber.gz
├── 2017-09-23
│   └── cyber.gz
└── 2017-09-24
    └── cyber.tar
```

**Example Use/Output**

As a one-liner with a line-break for readability:

```
$ while read -r ffn; do f="${ffn##*/}"; d="${ffn%/"$f"}"; last="${d##*/}"; \
echo -e "\ncp -a $ffn /archive/${last}_$f"; done < <(find tmp/ -type f)

cp -a tmp/2017-09-23/cyber.gz /archive/2017-09-23_cyber.gz
cp -a tmp/2017-09-22/cyber.gz /archive/2017-09-22_cyber.gz
cp -a tmp/2017-09-24/cyber.tar /archive/2017-09-24_cyber.tar
```

(newline added before output with `echo -e "\n..."` for clarity)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank david, Didn't get the clear picture on this.
1) ffn , f, d, last what i will use in my case ?
2) why there is three times cp at last. ?
In the server, There is are around 100 files called cyber.gz or .tar  and the word "cyber" is constant

Comment: The `cp -a ....` is the script **output**. (it will copy all the files found by `find`, regardless how may) I am just echoing the command that you would want to execute so I don't copy things all over my system `:)`. (that's what the `echo "cp -a $ffn /archive/${last}_$f"` does -- of course to actually copy, you need to remove the `echo` as explained -- or just add the actual `cp` command below it) The `ffn`, `f`, `d`, and `last` are just my shorthand for the variable names (I don't like to type), so I was giving you an explanation of what they represent.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls /tmp/*/* | sed 's/\/tmp\/\([^/]*\)\/\(.*\)/mv & \/tmp\/archive\/\1_\2/' > temp.sh

source temp.sh
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you are redirecting to temp.sh file?. There are almost 100 cyber.gz files in diff dates folder

Comment: I transform each filename to the command which renames the file.  The file temp.sh should contain all the commands. Then I run it.

You should look what is inside temp.sh , then you will understand it better.